# filtering ng-repeat with more than one conditional

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have this:

```
<div id="box" ng-repeat="item in produtos | filter:{categoria:busca.categoria,subcategoria:busca.subcat,produto:termoBusca}">
```

I've tested it with a condition and FINE, it worked:

```
filter:{busca.categoria?categoria:busca.categoria}
```

Now what I need is have more than one conditional, something like this:

```
filter:{busca.categoria?categoria:busca.categoria} && {busca.subcat?subcategoria:busca.subcat}
```

What is the correct way to write this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)

> Filters can be applied to the result of another filter. This is called "chaining" and uses the following syntax: {{ expression | filter1 | filter2 | ... }}

So, you just pipe, and It'll become something like this:

```
<div id="box" ng-repeat="item in produtos | filter:categoria:busca.categoria | filter:subcategoria:busca.subcat | filter:produto:termoBusca>
```

Comment: I did this, but no success:
<div id="box" ng-repeat="item in produtos | filter:{categoria:(busca.categoria?busca.categoria:'')} | filter:{subcat:(busca.subcat?busca.subcat:'')}">

With only the first pipe it works.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I was using an incorrect index subcat: when the valid one is subcategoria. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
filter:{categoria:(busca.categoria?categoria:busca.categoria) ,subcat: (busca.subcat?subcategoria:busca.subcat)}
```

filter parameter can be a object and property of the filter object must match with property of item of the array of object.

Comment: I did this, but no success:
<div id="box" ng-repeat="item in produtos | filter:{categoria:(busca.categoria?busca.categoria:''),subcat:(busca.subcat?busca.subcat:'')}">

Comment: If you read the answer of @inafalcao you will see a way that almost worked, it's getting close. With one pipe it worked as you can see in my comment on her answer.

Comment: can u share your object produtos?

Comment: Yeap! I'm lazy today... I was putting "subcat:"  when the correct key is "subcategoria". Now it worked, thanks bro!